# Making a simple Google App for a G Suite for education

Tags: google-app-engine

we are a high school with G Suite for Education, I'm a teacher and the computer coordinator (I studied computer engineering). I want to make a Google app for my students in order to increase their computer mental skills.

I have code scripts for Google spreadsheets and docs and I would like to know if there is a guide to make a Google app from nothing. It will be quite simple, a simple database for saving rankings and math operations with simple framework.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Questions asking to suggest a book or tutorial out of scope for Stack Overflow. For more details look at point 4 on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from Stack Overflow's Help Center.

Comment: You can find a quick start for App Engine in the official documentation. For example [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart).